# Compensation for working overtime on Saturdays

Tags: ethics, manager, india, compensation, overtime

I work in an American infrastructure firm based in India. We work on both American and Indian projects. My Indian client works on Saturday while our company does not. Because of the clients, I also have to work on Saturdays sometimes, even though I am not willing to work on Saturdays.

However, my manager prevents me from putting the Saturday work on the time sheet. He says we cannot show Saturday work to our US offices (US office manages all the finance and administration) and cannot charge it to the time sheet since it will affect the project profits.

Our office does have an overtime policy. The manager has never talked about this to us. Which implies that he is not going to allow us to charge the overtime.

Here I have two options:

1. Either ask him a compensatory day off on weekday for working on Saturday (There's no provision for compensatory day off in our office rules, but he can give a comp off unofficially)
2. Convince him to let me charge the Saturday on the timesheet.

What are the advantages and drawbacks of these options?

Comment: @Xander "I also have to work on Saturdays sometimes though I am not willing to work on Saturdays" It seems that the manager is forcing OP to work on Saturday but without reporting the time spent.

Comment: I started work "on the clock" so you were paid according to the clock hours late was late etc Also, will you be covered by work insurance if working Saturday is not recognized?

Comment: Are you actually working in US or in India? I see that answers assume you work in US, but the question tag is "India".

Comment: "*cannot charge it to the time sheet since it will affect the project profits.*" Did he really said that? You have to work on Saturday for free because it would kill profitability? Nice business model. This is pretty much definition of a sweat shop... Or I have misunderstood something. I understand everything along time zone-differences, flexible schedule vs administrative burden, but citing lack of profitability due to worked hours is flat out wage theft. Unbelievable.

Comment: This sounds kind of fishy.  Are you sure your supervisor isn't having your violate corporate rules?  It kind of sounds like it.

Comment: @luk32 I do not think you have misunderstood anything. Unfortunately there are such places (not very common but not unheard of as well) in India.

Answer (score 187):

You're missing the obvious third option:

3. Stop working on Saturdays

It's clear you're not allowed to work on Saturdays so you should stop doing it. If your manager tries to force you anyway you kindly respond with:

> Of course I would work on Saturday if you need me to, as long as I can officially enter those hours in my time-sheet and receive the proper compensation.

If the client asks you to work on a Saturday you try to professionally explain why you will not.

> Sorry for the inconvenience but Saturday isn't an official workday in the US and I'm no longer allowed to put in overtime in the weekend. I'll come back to you first thing Monday morning. If the issue cannot wait till Monday please contact [manager] to find a solution.
>
> kind regards,
> chrono

Comment: +1 for the extra option. Although very direct, this is the method I would suggest if you've already tried to ask about working Saturdays and your boss has said you can't do that due to US offices then you should just stop working. If it burns bridges then it's your bosses problem

Comment: Good reply but I would definitely not tell the client about the inner workings of the company and indirectly expose my manager, who in the end of the day is following company policy while the OP isn't. Just limit the reply to: "The company is closed on Saturdays, I'll get back to you Monday. For urgent matters, contact [manager] [email]."

Comment: @Xander Situational. I wrote it this way because OP was already working on saterdays so now stating "the office is closed on Saterdays" could be confusing. Note that nowhere in that response I'm blaming manager. I'm only offering to contact the manager to find a solution (for example: perhaps HE can work overtime on saterday to solve the issue).

Comment: Simply "stop working" (no-show) may create problems, make sure you communicate that you are not working, with proper reason, in writing, in advance, to avoid any charges of "insubordination" etc etc.

Comment: @UKMonkey It's not only about the company, OP is also exposed to the customer and the customer may expect people to be working on Saturdays. Also, we don't know what sort of work agreement is there between the company and client or,  OP and client, so suggesting to no-show blindly may blow back. My suggestion is to keep OP safe from any possible back-fires.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Given that the answer explains that you state that either you're not working on saturdays, or you're going to fill out the timesheet; it is communicated. I don't see what your comments add.

Comment: @UKMonkey It's clarity.

Comment: @Xander from the sound of it, it seems the manager is NOT following company policy. That's just based on my doubt that company policy would demand something so obviously illegal though, nothing concrete.

Comment: Never, ever, work off the clock. That time is often not covered by insurance, and can be disavowed by your company as reckless behaviour.

Don't respond to emails on the weekend, don't work for free. Your time in clearly valuable to both you, and the company. Respect yourself.

Comment: @Malisbad Yeah, there's horror stories. "Can you work this Saturday? Shouldn't be a regular thing." It becomes a regular thing. "Boss, I can't keep working Saturdays." "You're fired for violating company policies. You know there's no overtime on the weekend, you've put the whole company at risk!" And unless you have email evidence showing they <strike>told</strike> "asked" you to work on Saturday, you're hooped.

Comment: *If you replace skill with effort, there is no end to what you cannot do* - one of my favorite sayings. If - on average - you cannot finish your job within the alloted time for it, something is wrong with you or your position. Change something with either, you shouldn't expect it to change by itself.

Answer (score 45):

As you mention it, it sounds like your manager is stopping you from making fair usage of the company policy. It's bad.

Reach out to the HR, immediately. This is a malpractice that needs to stop. Simply put, your manager is asking you to work for free to show up the profit in the balance sheet. That's unfair and not correct.

As you mentioned, your manager already mentioned about the "profit" and did not inform you to use the overtime policy - it's understood that he is not doing this by mistake, this is a deliberate attempt.

Detail the situation in writing to HR. Mention the nature of the work request and ask what alternative could be arranged to see that you are properly compensated.

> *Either ask him a compensatory off on weekday for working on Saturday (There's no provision for compensatory off in our office rules, but he can give a comp off unoficially)*

I'd not take that path. If something is not in the rulebook, don't use it. It may or may not be honored, if the current arrangement changes.

- Also, if it's you who asks for it, you can be in a tricky situation in case there's a problem later on.
- In case it's your manager proposing this out-of-the-book arrangement, it's less problematic for you, but given that the process is still outside company policy, in case of any conflicts, you'll lose all the comp-offs or similar.

> *Convince him to let me charge the Saturday in timesheet.*

You already tried that and received a refusal - it's very less likely that the answer will change on a second request. Better use the proper channel.

Moreover,

> *He says we cannot show Saturday work to our US offices (US office manages all the finance and administration) and cannot charge it to the time sheet since it will affect the project profits*

That clearly indicates, your manager is incapable of managing. It's your managers (one of the many) responsibility to take care of the interests of the employees' working with them, not try to take advantage. In case you see this to be a company-wide policy (or,location-based malpractice), rather than a one-off case with your project / manager, it's time to find a new job.

## In the end, if your time is not honored, it's not worth the time and effort.

Comment: This is dangerous advice politically speaking. Going over the manager's head like that may work but is also likely to cause a lot of grief.

Comment: @TimB OK, and stealing the effort from one is not dangerous? In case this is a practice, and a known pattern, I would not think twice to burn all the bridges. Seriously, you don't honor my time, you don't honor me.

Comment: @TimB since the manager goes over *the company's head* by assertively sneaking 53 extra unpaid work days per year into *his* profits sheet I don't see how it is out of line with the culture he is fomenting. The grief started the moment he decided to do this and I can only see it getting worse if nobody stands up.

Comment: I agree that the manager is out of order. I'm just warning that following this advice means walking into a mine field. The OP needs to go into that with their eyes open.

Comment: I'd add to this that if there is an agreement reached that the OP will get comp-time for working on Saturdays, then get the agreement in writing. If it's not in writing, then the OP could experience a situation later where they are disciplined or dismissed for missing work during the week.

Comment: Another option is to report this issue to the US Department of Labor as well as HR after you get another job. And yes, you should get another job. Going thru HR makes you a target.

Comment: I do not agree with this or at least the first part. In most such places, HR is just a puppet completely controlled by the local boss. This will not do any good.

Answer (score 18):

> He says we cannot show Saturday work to our US offices (US office manages all the finance and administration) and cannot charge it to the time sheet since it will affect the project profits.

You cannot charge for your work because it will affect the project profits?  With that kind of argument he can stop paying you altogether and, should that not make the project profitable, demand that you pony up what is missing.  If company and/or manager failed to account for the project's costs due to different working conditions in U.S. and India, that is not your problem.  It is your manager's problem to account and budget for it and make sure ends meet or design a mitigation strategy (which might involve offering overtime payment for additional work/hours required from you) and/or pull the plug.  That's why he is getting a manager's pay and job, and you are getting a worker's pay and job.

He is trying to get credit for not doing his job and stealing work hours from you.  This is a matter for escalation: first to HR.  If that doesn't help, the department of labor.  Your manager will likely be willing to throw you under the bus (making you work without pay definitely does not show that he has your interest in mind), so be prepared for retaliation and document everything.  You don't know how much he is backed by HR in his attempt of exploitation, so make sure your resume is up to date.  At the latest when escalation to HR does not result in immediate changes, you also might want to secure the services of a lawyer before considering further steps.

Answer (score 5):

A small addition to the excellent other answers: in some countries, though maybe not in India, there is still another, more sneaky option: document your time at work (there is software that lets you track your logon and logoff times on your computer; if you use source control commit times may also be useful) and then sue them at some point for your overtime pay. E.g. after changing to your next job.

In my experience there is a strong correlation between not properly paying employees and other forms of disrespect, so you might want to find a different job anyway.

P.S. If you want to simply stop working on Saturdays as suggested in answer #1, it might be worth finding something that keeps you from coming to the office. E.g. older family members need your time, younger family members need to be brought to saturday school, your bicycle/soccer/charity club only meets on saturdays, you have booked a language course that takes place on saturdays etc.

Comment: IANAL, but if you want to sue a company over forced unpaid overtime, you need first and foremost prove that you were *forced* to do it. Source control timestamps prove that the OP worked on a Saturday, but don't attest whose idea that was.

Comment: Where I live, you only have to prove that you were on your workplace and were not paid for your time :)

Comment: There is a soft limit above which the courts will assume that your salary covers overtime, but that is way above what ordinary  software developers earn here. 100000 USD p.a. or so.

Comment: What prevents you from voluntarily doing some minor work (e.g. writing e-mails) on a Saturday, then suing your company for unpaid overtime?

Comment: Reasonably reliable time tracking. But if the employee can show that his superiors were aware that he  regularly worked without entering it on his timesheet, or that he was not the only one, the assumption will be that the company's timesheet is less reliable than the employee's timesheet.

Comment: Generally the assumption is that if the employee is at his workplace and the employer is not telling him to leave, the employer has to pay. Probably because experience has shown that there are more employers wjo screw their employees than the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

> He says we cannot show Saturday work to our US offices (US office manages all the finance and administration)

And? I (and my whole team) just worked Saturday and Sunday for my current position (a US government contractor that does not normally operate on the weekends) in order to crunch for a deadline (and I'll be paid for it). Your manager's statement here is meaningless.

> and cannot charge it to the time sheet since it will affect the project profits.

Obviously hours you work and don't charge for will affect the profit differently than hours you work and DO charge for. This is a meaningless excuse ("if the company pays you, the company will have less money!" Well, duh, that's how a financial transaction works). Either the project isn't budgeted properly, your manager is trying to get free work out of you (and possibly has a financial incentive himself to get you to do so; eg. if they are paid by percentage of profit), or something else is going on (say, your company is about to run out of money and go bankrupt, so scam all the employees for every hour possible).

You should be paid for your hours, regardless of when they occur. It isn't "overtime" until the law says its overtime (usually the total number of hours in a week but I am not familiar with how India operates), not the days of the week (usually), or the time of day (though nightshift work tends to pay a higher base wage).

If you have a lot of unpaid hours racked up at this point (pretty much "more than 0" but the more you have, the higher the incentive) you should contact a lawyer or other agency that deals in abusive work practices and report your company for not paying you for hours worked.

And oh yeah.

Find a new job.

Answer (score 2):

I face the same problem. Same environment (India, IT, Timesheet).
I have fixed my problem. I think this issue of your manager over asserting themself isn't an isolated event. It usually starts with small favors. In my case, they started with calling me during off hours to get an update. Slowly update turned to small hotfixes in production and so on and so forth. The thing to understand is that its difficult for managers also to make such a request. They risk dissent among other things.
Here's what I did. I stopped taking calls after 9pm. I just reject the calls point blank. I have never been questioned why I do that. If they insist working on saturday or a sunday( Arab clients) I'll make up a personal plan and tell them its not possible. They'll do it twice or thrice before they get the message.
In my opinion, instead of outright citing labour laws or company poiicy, its better to be subtle. That's how they (manager) put you in this state afterall.
My manager is a nice person. Has a kid. Struggles like all of us. Don't put the onus of them crossing the boundaries only on them. Keep rigid boundaries and you should start to feel the difference.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the other aspects that have been mentioned it should be pointed out that this is likely to be regarded as **fraud**. I used to work for an american company although based in the UK and they were constant reminders that our time sheets were reflected in the company balance sheet and therefore it was imperative that they were accurate and honest. There was even guidance about how to escalate if anyone asked you to do work that wasn't to be reflected on your timesheet.  Might be worth looking at your policies to see if there is anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

While the top voted answer is absolutely correct and right thing to do, knowing how things work in India (not everywhere but at the companies where "bosses" match the description you gave), I just do not think it will work in your case.

1) You can leave the job as others have rightly described it as 'malpractice' or 'sweat-shop'. There are plenty of other companies in India where ethical standards are very high.

2) If leaving is not an option for you right now, just go with your second option. Unofficially ask for a compensatory off on weekdays and live with it if it is granted. This may actually work well for you but do note that this unofficial leave may also require him to fudge the numbers somewhere. (As in show your work on Saturday as work done on weekday). You need to decide how comfortable you are with this and take a call.

Comment: I think it wasn't any Indian company, but an American one that caused the problem. Even though it happened in India.